# How can I remove the "Awards Cup" from superuser/stackexchange at the web browser level eg Chrome?

Tags: browser, google-chrome-extensions

Is it possible to remove the "Awards Cup" from superuser at the web browser level?

This thing

[image]

which sometimes looks like e.g. [image]

I don't want to know if somebody upvoted me. or if I got some points.  (I might want to know if I got a downvote, but for simplicity, let's say I want to remove it completely, which is preferable to me than having it there)

This is not a request for a feature, so it's not a question for meta. As i'm asking re me making this change at the browser level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at tampermonkey or similar, it allows you to run code (javascript) automatically on a page based on url. using it you could create a script that removes or hides the element.

```
$('.achievements-button-item').hide()
```

full script I just created

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Remove achievements on SU
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://superuser.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    $('.achievements-button-item').hide();
})();
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to recognise that jquery for me https://i.imgur.com/KTd52AG.png

Comment: I have the warning as well but it continues and works.

Comment: You're right. Though for some reason when the script is enabled, I can't add a comment or accept an answer, when I have the extension disabled. The add a comment link jumps to the top of the page.  But it does work in removing the trophy icon. And the fact that I can't add a comment is more of a question for stackoverflow . So I accept your answer

Comment: It could be a conflict with the require jquery line in the script provided. try removing the @require line and see if it still happens.

Comment: You're right, removing that line that read `// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js`  fixedd that. So now I can add comments

Comment: The cup does flash up for a moment when the page loads.. Perhaps there's a way to make that adjustment before the page even gets displayed?